# Creating command button on Navigation worksheet for all other worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, button, for-loop, worksheet

Current code:

```
Sub CreateFormsButton()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim btn As Button
Dim rng As Range
Dim counter As String
counter = 6

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     If ws.Name = "Navigation" Or ws.Name = "Todo" Then
     Else
     With ws
        Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Navigation").Range("C" + CStr(counter))
        Set btn = .Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height * 2)
     With btn
        .Caption = ws.Name
        .OnAction = "GoToWS"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 16
     End With
     End With
     End If
     counter = counter + 2
Next ws

End Sub
```

The code sort of works as is, however, the buttons are being placed on the worksheets themselves instead of the Navigation worksheet as intended. Am I doing something incorrectly by setting `Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Navigation").Range("C" + CStr(counter))`? This doesn't seem to be having any effect on where the button is being placed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe use `Set btn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Navigation").Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height * 2) `?

Comment: *sigh*, I'd give you a check mark if I could. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Wasn't use if the Buttons collection was Workbook wide or WorkSheet wide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the button in the Buttons collection of the Navigation Sheet.

```
Set btn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Navigation").Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height * 2)
```